# what if I need to put a "" inside a "" in bash shell?

Tags: shell, quoting

I have a shell script, in which there is a command:

`if [ -e "./${name}/\"$1\"_page.json" ];`

I noticed that unlike many other languages, the `\"` doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Please define _"doesn't work"_. If the purpose is to check for existence of a file called `./foo/"bar"_page.json` (assuming `$name` is `foo` and `$1` is `bar`), then it should work. Run with `set -x` to see what happens.

Comment: I see in your title, you have "fancy" quotes. The shell only understands plain ASCII quotes `'` and `"`

Comment: Which shell are you using? If you don't know, what does `echo "$SHELL"` print?

Comment: `SHELL` contains the name of your default shell, not necessarily the shell you are running.

Comment: @glennjackman No, that's a design misfeature that [the developers are refusing to fix](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/site-design-updates/3432#comment5263_3432). The quotes in the title are ASCII quotes but they're displayed as English quotes. I've [raised this as a bug](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/leave-double-quotes-in-title-alone) (I'm sure this isn't the first time but I can't find any previous trace as a separate question).

Answer (score 3):

use triple double quote ?

```
    if [ -e "./${name}/"""$1"""_page.json" ];
```

this will

- replace `${name}` and `$1` by actual values.

please note:

```
archemar@mybox:~/tmp7$ foo=bar
archemar@mybox:~/tmp7$ f2=deux
archemar@mybox:~/tmp7$ echo "${f2}/"""${foo}"""/test.php"
deux/bar/test.php
archemar@mybox:~/tmp7$ echo "${f2}/\"${foo}\"/test.php"
deux/"bar"/test.php
```

as pointed out, your desired result is a bit unclear.

Comment: Triple quotes just reduce to a single quote; the first two or last two (depending on it starts out of or in a double-quoted string) simply reduce to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use single-quotes.

```
if [ -e './${name}/"$1"_page.json' ];
```

Note that if you want `${name}` and `$1` to be expanded, you can't use single quotes. [Read this article for the difference between strong and weak quoting.](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-8)

However, if you want to expand arguments it's perfectly fine to concatenate strings:

```
if [ -e './'"${name}"'"'"$1"'"_page.json' ];
```

Though many `'` characters render this almost unreadable.

Comment: `$1` will not be replaced inside single quote.

Comment: That's assuming you want to check for existence of a file called `./${name}/"$1"_page.json` literally, that is with the `${name}` and `$1` _not_ expanded.

Comment: I am aware of that. Yet it's unclear what was intention of OP.

Comment: You can write `[ -e './'"${name}"'/"'"$1"'"_page.json' ]`.

Comment: Okay, updated to take both versions into account.

Comment: Thanks for downvote, please provide explanation so I can improve my answer.

Comment: unlike awk, you don't use spaces to concatenate strings in shell: `[ -e './' ${name} '"' $1 '"_page.json' ]` gives 7 arguments to the `[` command. You want `[ -e './'"${name}"'"'"$1"'"_page.json' ]`

Comment: Updated with your version. I checked on command which accepted multiple arguments.

Comment: Gives an error with bash, dash, zsh. ksh for some reason accepts it.

Comment: @glennjackman What error? I tried it out in bash and it works for me.

Comment: `if [ -e './' ${name} '"' $1 '"_page.json' ]; then echo ok; fi` ==>
`bash: [: too many arguments`

Comment: @glennjackman You're not using the command I provided.